# Run functions in different files

Tags: javascript

I've several JS files; the first one is a library to be used by the next ones, and every one of those another files have a function *main()* which calls the functions of that file.

lib.js => library

a.js :: main() => call functions in a.js
b.js :: main() => call functions in b.js
...
...

So, I would want that were run the function *main* for those files (after of loading *lib.js*).

How do run each function *main* after of loading the JS file?
It would be load *a.js* and run *main*, load *b.js* and run *main*, ...

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? How do you get what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JavaScript is not C** or something similar.

It doesn't matter in which file you define the function. The function will be overwritten.

So if you first load the file `a.js` and then the file `b.js` The `main` function will be the `main` function which you've defined in `b.js` and the `main` function you've defined in `a.js` won't exists anywhere.

If you want to keep old functions I recommend you to create an object in each file and define the main function in it. So something like this.

`a.js`:

```
var a = {};
a.main = function() {
    /* do stuff */
};
```

`b.js`:

```
var b = {};
b.main = function() {
    /* do stuff */
};
```

So now you can call:

```
a.main();
```

and

```
b.main();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to control the dependencies (order of load), use something like `head.js` or `require.js`.

However, don't pollute your global namespace by reusing the global function name `main` in all of your JS files.  There's plenty of documentation on the web about how to avoid polluting global namespace and why it's a good idea.  It's an easy web search.

More info in the answers here: [How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration)